# Relative path from a class java

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, path

I have a problem with a relative path in my Java EE application, here's is the situation:

1. I'm trying to parse an xml file that i have in `/WebContent/files/queries.xml` using SaxParser API.
2. When I'm providing this path (`./files/queries.xml`) in a java class so that i can perform the parsing operation, I'm getting a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/james/./files/queries.xml` !

Could someone please help me with that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

WebContent is the location of your webapp sources. When deployed, everything is bundled into a war file, and can't be accessed using file IO.

Use [`ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to get a resource from your webapp's context.

Comment: Thank's for the answer, actually i'm not using a servlet, but a simple java class ... so how can i do this ?

Comment: Your class runs inside a webapp. Pass the servlet context to your class in order to be able to access it. Or store the file in the WEB-INF/classes directory, along with the webapp's classes, and load it using `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream()`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the real path you can just do:

```
String path = s.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WebContent/files/queries.xml");
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer, actually i'm not using a servlet, but a simple java class ... so how can i do this ?

Comment: What type of container are you using?